# How to disable displaying of errors in php and log them in a file

Tags: php, error-reporting

I'm trying to disable displaying of errors in a file and just log them into a log file

```
<?php
error_reporting('E_ALL');
echo $x;
?>
```

The log file works when I remove the error_reporting('E_ALL') but then the errors are also displayed.
Is there another way to do this, but disabling error reporting on specific pages only.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom error handling function and set it via [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/function.set-error-handler.php):

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile = null, $errline = 0, $errcontext = null)
{
    // Append $errstr and other useful information to a file
    @file_put_contents('error_log', "ERROR: $errstr\n", FILE_APPEND);

    return true; // disable regular PHP error reporting
});
```

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.julianbez.com/blog/2006/02/19/how-to-set-up-error-logging-with-php/

Hope that helps...

Comment: I couldn't post the source code for this because of the license on the site.